# Activate and Focus HTA window using VBscripting

Tags: windows, vbscript, hta

I have developed several HTA files where each file calls the other.
There is one HTA file that i need (if called) to stay as the "Always on top" window while it is open.

I have tried "AppActivate" function thru an infinite loop using Vb script however i always find that it activates the window in the taskbar but does not make the HTA file always on top.

Searched up and down, couldn't find working way to get it working in reliable way that does not involve 3rd party applications.

My HTA file code:

```
<html>
<hta:application id="oHTA"
    border="none"
    caption="no"
    contextmenu="no"
    innerborder="no"
    scroll="no"
    showintaskbar="no"
/>
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_OnLoad
        'Resize and position the window
        width = 133 : height = 25
        window.resizeTo width, height
        window.moveTo ((Screen.Width / 3)*2),0
    End Sub
    
    Sub CallMain ()
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run("Main.hta")
        window.close 'close this HTA
    End Sub
    
</script>
<body background="Strt.png" onclick="CallMain">
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Within the HTA itself, have you tried `window.focus` via `setInterval`?

Comment: I don't think vbscript lets you make a window always on top.

Comment: @LesFerch yes this was one of may failed attempts, would work sometimes but most of the times not

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and had the same result. It's a difficult problem because, by design, the user is supposed to be in control of what window is on top. Is there any way you could redesign to have just one HTA? Maybe multiple frames?

Comment: I am open for re-design, can you elaborate further on your idea ?

Comment: It depends on what your HTA files do and what they display. If I could see your code, I could provide better advice. Can you post a short version here? If not, I recommend making a GitHub repository to share your code. Barring that, all I can suggest is either set up multiple pages in one HTA with forward and back buttons or create a main HTA with a one [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for each of the other HTMs (i.e. change their extension from HTA to HTM). If that sounds like something that will work for you, let me know and I'll write up an answer with sample code.

Comment: I edited the question with my full HTA code added, basically it is very small icon that appears on the top of the screen where a user can simply click it. On click would call another HTA file. Yes Multiple pages in one HTA is something I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example HTA with multiple pages. This should simplify the issue of focus.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application id=oHTA
    border=none
    caption=no
    contextmenu=no
    innerborder=no
    scroll=no
    showintaskbar=no
>
<script language="VBScript">
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

MyPath  = Mid(document.URL,8)
MyFolder = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(MyPath)
oWSH.CurrentDirectory = MyFolder

Sub window_onLoad
  StartPage
End Sub

Sub StartPage
  HideAllPages
  window.document.body.background = "Strt.png"
  iStartPage.style.display = "inline"
  window.resizeTo 133, 25
  window.moveTo ((screen.availWidth / 3)*2),0
End Sub

Sub MainPage
  HideAllPages
  window.document.body.background = "Main.png"
  iMainPage.style.display = "inline"
  CenterWindow 800,600
End Sub

Sub SubPage1
  HideAllPages
  window.document.body.background = "Sub1.png"
  iSubPage1.style.display = "inline"
  CenterWindow 640,480
End Sub

Sub SubPage2
  HideAllPages
  window.document.body.background = "Sub2.png"
  iSubPage1.style.display = "inline"
  CenterWindow 640,480
End Sub

Sub HideAllPages
  iStartPage.style.display = "none"
  iMainPage.style.display = "none"
  iSubPage1.style.display = "none"
  iSubPage2.style.display = "none"
End Sub

Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    window.resizeTo x, y
    window.moveTo (screen.availWidth - x)/2, (screen.availHeight - y)/2
End Sub

</script>
<style>
body {background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:no-repeat}
.sb {background-color:transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border:none;
    cursor:pointer; overflow:hidden; outline:none; width:100%}
</style>
<body>
<div id=iStartPage>
  <input class=sb type=button onclick=MainPage()>
</div>
<div id=iMainPage>
  <input type=button value=Back onclick=StartPage()>
  <input type=button value=SubPage1 onclick=SubPage1()>
  <input type=button value=SubPage2 onclick=SubPage2()>
</div>
<div id=iSubPage1>
  <input type=button value=Back onclick=MainPage()>
</div>
<div id=iSubPage2>
  <input type=button value=Back onclick=MainPage()>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```